# how do I get access to the value of myCountry?

Tags: javascript, html

I have code for an auto-completing program, but I want to make it into a website search bar. What I need to know, is how to get access to the value of `myCountry`.

Here's the part with `myCountry`:

```html
<form autocomplete="off" action="/action_page.php">
<div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
<input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Country">
</div>
```

Once I know how to do that, I think that I can just put an `if else` statement into a JavaScript code.

What I thought I should do is use the `getElementById()` function, but I'm new to html and JavaScript so I have no idea on what to do.

Here's a link to the full code=>
[link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_autocomplete)

Comment: `let myCountry = document.getElementById('myInput')`

Comment: I tried this if(document.getElementById('myInput')=="Uganda"){
            document.body.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
        }                                                                                                                                and it didn't work

Comment: `document.getElementById('myInput').value`

Comment: I tried this if(document.getElementById('myInput').value=="Uganda"){ document.body.style.backgroundColor="yellow"; } but it still didn't work.Am I even allowed to do this if else statement with this code? You could look at the code with the link.

Comment: When you compare strings the values are case-sensitive, so `Uganda` is not the same as `uganda`

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G3NK5O9H2QL9

Comment: @Rick Sibley Ahh. I see now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.getElementById()`, and pass it a string. This will return information about the element, which you can use to do whatever you need with  your application.

Here are some basic usage examples:

```js
let myCountry = document.getElementById('myInput')

console.log(myCountry.placeholder)
console.log(myCountry.tagName)
console.log(myCountry.getAttribute('type'))

document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', e => {
  console.log(myCountry.value)
  switch(myCountry.value.toLowerCase()) {
    case 'uganda': document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow'; break;
    case 'canada': document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red'; break;
    case 'china': document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'green'; break;
    default: document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'white'; break;
  }
})
```

```html
<form autocomplete="off" action="/action_page.php">
  <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Country">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Get Input Value">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I can't believe it! It works! thank you so much. I'm pretty sure from here I can make it take me to a different page just like a website search bar. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can definitely use the `getElementById`. e.g.

```
let country = document.getElementById('myInput').value
```

But I think you should also see this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-text-input-field-using-javascript) to learn about various other methods